# Drupal SQL table how to insert edit button on each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal

I've got a table in Drupal with the following code:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "moocow");
mysql_select_db("vedb", $db); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT NodeID,NodeDesc,NodeZone,Fusion,DSLID FROM      `nodeidtable` WHERE DSLID != '' AND `NodeZone` = 'CLOSED' ORDER BY NodeID ASC"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<th>CLOSED SITES</th>"; 
echo "<th></th>"; 
echo "<th></th>"; 
echo "<th></th>"; 
echo "<th></th>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<th>Node ID</th>"; 
echo "<th>Node Address</th>"; 
echo "<th>Node Zone</th>"; 
echo "<th>Fusion Status</th>"; 
echo "<th>Service Number</th>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
//display the data 
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
  echo "<tr>"; 
  foreach ($rows as $data) 
  { 
    echo "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>"; 
  } 
} 

echo "<br>";
echo "<tr>"; 


echo "</table>"; 

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Now I can change it renders the td to include the individual columns, but I really want to add a little edit button on the right-hand side which will let me edit that particular row fields.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while loop with the following code:

```
 while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
 { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach ($rows as $data) 
    { 
       echo "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>"; 
    }


   //create link for current node edit
    echo "<td align='center'>". l(t('Edit this node'), 'node/' . $row['NodeId'] . '/edit') ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
 }
```

Remove `echo "<br>"; and echo "<tr>";` below to while loop. This will resolve the issue for you

Comment: Thanks. I receive this error: "The requested page "/?q=node%2F%2Fedit&render=overlay" could not be found.". Should I be creating a new page?

Comment: @jimps: It seems like `$row['NodeId']` doesn't output anything. Please check if this produce the node id. Do also check your clean url and mod_rewrite settings.